# significance letter above bar graphic in wrong order

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to put some letter above my bars, but they are in the wrong order... I want them in the order I put in the variable "Number", but they keep popping up odd: I suppose it has to do with the geom_text function, namely the dodge position, but I can't figure out how to correct it... any help would be amazing. Thank you in advance. Here's my code, str and dput:

```
library(ggplot2)

Number <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
            "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
            "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
            "a", "b", "b", "c", "c",
            "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
            "ab", "a", "ab", "ab", "b",
            "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")
aa1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=mean)
bb1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=sd)
ee1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=std.error)
cc1 <- merge(aa1, ee1, by=c("day", "type"))
colnames(cc1)[3:4] <- c("mean", "se")

ggplot(cc1, aes(x = type, y = mean, fill = day))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position= "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="", y="", title="") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se,
                    ymax = mean+se), 
                position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Number, y = mean+se),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-1.5, size = 4) +
  ylim(0, 60)
```

```
> str(IBRindex)
tibble [280 × 5] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ treatment    : chr [1:280] "control" "control" "control" "control" ...
 $ concentration: num [1:280] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ day          : chr [1:280] "day 00" "day 00" "day 00" "day 00" ...
 $ IBR          : num [1:280] 2.67 3.75 1.61 2.57 5.03 ...
 $ type         : chr [1:280] "control" "control" "control" "control" ...
> dput(IBRindex)
structure(list(treatment = c("control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
"control", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", 
"nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "nZn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn", 
"Zn", "Zn", "Zn", "Zn"), concentration = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), day = c("day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", "day 00", 
"day 00", "day 00", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 07", 
"day 07", "day 07", "day 07", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", 
"day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 14", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", 
"day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 21", "day 28", "day 28", 
"day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28", "day 28"), 
    IBR = c(2.67462331695747, 3.7479797373072, 1.61046032674323, 
    2.56950238487896, 5.03075234402507, 5.37002116681056, 2.64141437772882, 
    4.9152463455487, 4.42398965325598, 2.57401154377605, 4.26241807174544, 
    4.33363358865668, 3.78897823874461, 3.48312036957065, 3.99416070655978, 
    1.93968782769081, 4.75093722363259, 5.51898417813521, 4.92673489859106, 
    5.39137927971847, 3.37992396426374, 4.07343918184835, 3.51926696984851, 
    4.43933430396208, 5.18381909436977, 6.61833294871228, 3.72823589777794, 
    3.66207119102597, 4.39594075614386, 4.97247504419813, 4.30455888495827, 
    3.77456618281378, 5.09472273390474, 3.05262919848668, 3.07142757916952, 
    4.25225206271389, 3.76082832603328, 3.73885894087054, 3.09794148143722, 
    3.77133967738412, 4.41367079910091, 3.45189694907517, 4.92317209577327, 
    5.22130368414091, 4.07751905688481, 3.1824348981764, 4.60198451801424, 
    3.96801799883429, 2.96092797308633, 5.02773896528037, 3.03385473926719, 
    2.36963181427078, 3.21526643115091, 4.85778412914227, 4.02935482617193, 
    2.02544112163022, 5.04965471996493, 4.74349499147982, 5.91949941706675, 
    4.92929828210668, 4.69889231287052, 4.30963768140504, 6.08877294155499, 
    6.98074965355127, 4.14882984161724, 3.56916522338602, 4.39217960852649, 
    3.9669746362046, 6.65355559214861, 6.94564915063743, 3.94949791221281, 
    6.37414803526681, 6.98432010685677, 5.77316975099232, 4.94488474439672, 
    6.9861048633483, 5.63849809423475, 6.29166008635028, 5.74415404471756, 
    3.6372083091033, 4.01070581242574, 4.8655962593264, 1.88413883731, 
    4.79275227153052, 3.81120520821257, 4.47090351843292, 3.16618143015861, 
    3.23851666260324, 4.77146055149409, 4.47129218350255, 2.05558098673713, 
    3.79084112791848, 3.07302616784798, 3.4978815709687, 2.66953653183652, 
    3.19038087969454, 5.21012090757653, 5.32648828917726, 2.56942255547836, 
    5.5907008793165, 5.53854697198559, 5.87983669121639, 6.03733304910772, 
    6.56755065614165, 7.10332216881151, 4.81177585751042, 4.54798238224535, 
    3.95193032380064, 6.67575589644939, 6.06869025907535, 4.37845435250039, 
    2.62208875960694, 6.93407258605974, 4.93097925714361, 5.20374733855494, 
    7.51073530828615, 5.88385298939511, 5.96553142088359, 4.66273611270057, 
    4.90834498697629, 2.87215820785464, 3.31268369074254, 4.71296500261797, 
    4.51762544390301, 3.66598229704196, 3.44834187424463, 5.39326959894371, 
    3.03697388465155, 17.8148410995284, 14.659130519738, 15.6981725881571, 
    14.6812327837703, 17.514860326209, 17.3038688917875, 13.821325216362, 
    17.5465685744476, 21.3916254334255, 22.8074223758046, 22.9887518444997, 
    24.2183714264532, 23.5844811482723, 23.5153604180435, 23.8459251937961, 
    22.0480621597051, 35.8289072217775, 34.8254568142626, 33.8355866295228, 
    33.4983475202167, 31.8714740466038, 36.2030158821273, 35.1271378686553, 
    35.2900740168341, 51.5374998706194, 48.8315209337556, 50.8900085162866, 
    49.2638338839193, 53.6306040574627, 51.7754205002004, 54.1103470968817, 
    53.8807651408743, 4.16942600450941, 3.32447314543023, 4.8040715971597, 
    4.41177094089401, 4.42197820078452, 2.50469159668196, 4.40060099388344, 
    2.84298752065672, 5.34668806802852, 6.97624375926234, 6.02438223306577, 
    6.22607736061035, 5.40739447179978, 4.33051515127305, 5.46447309334728, 
    7.90422586261291, 5.28896215775905, 9.38815352811245, 5.68736468030214, 
    7.79920093302827, 6.27603266817483, 7.77085551528006, 4.04676878201731, 
    7.34266173532591, 3.04404873376128, 3.30533976874861, 3.20204864353914, 
    3.51093114543373, 5.17894706197435, 5.83706795653512, 4.07974686686356, 
    4.8018698231442, 5.25546376688219, 6.88712890119132, 6.54482807860982, 
    7.0614835486993, 5.31936374195468, 4.46153000933164, 5.57359045463827, 
    5.77661149869279, 4.32943598873242, 4.99737409633889, 5.30239861267007, 
    5.21865911291923, 3.94187397009296, 3.7677394532681, 2.60391866677532, 
    4.078600099203, 2.10838652255303, 3.33485224239033, 1.8865090072732, 
    3.55412071048938, 3.4416492884528, 3.75837165940665, 3.47747787733748, 
    2.91863269209712, 4.3442209371281, 3.58625360096082, 3.47267199292155, 
    4.32148247554021, 4.0171670781028, 6.29574132366701, 6.27453146835221, 
    4.72793112332731, 6.61183849815556, 5.22654806974128, 4.39592240776659, 
    3.38127049182744, 5.36447103298555, 4.1250393285919, 6.29666635726061, 
    2.11824381367106, 4.76345856507143, 6.74205788863044, 7.02785125626737, 
    5.5074610375801, 4.32309859649177, 5.07126739994846, 6.9573581171769, 
    4.96744713883356, 4.05985806174783, 5.68177170421745, 2.6493597596968, 
    1.92583897945382, 2.80129784875938, 3.02460897499231, 2.95604158816199, 
    5.62122308297042, 14.5591671165735, 16.8309249651598, 13.8725088166687, 
    14.3334722261771, 15.6797414751417, 16.9487075554227, 17.7763627725153, 
    11.2791150723411, 18.1353046187642, 20.9657621187182, 17.6286569411618, 
    18.8106238376261, 19.1457711473124, 16.9622226206267, 18.7668436783958, 
    15.5848150373948, 23.7017133530339, 25.485996914625, 27.2277374484164, 
    25.8162516336272, 28.0618081156315, 28.44402686578, 21.7274399766543, 
    27.2150256922317, 29.3366452644784, 29.2069564349921, 29.517194513526, 
    28.4026166420608, 32.8808833862209, 26.5462514119385, 29.8411268215413, 
    30.268325525242), type = c("control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", "control", 
    "control", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", 
    "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", 
    "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", 
    "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", 
    "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", 
    "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn1_", "nZn10_", 
    "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", 
    "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", 
    "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", 
    "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", 
    "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", 
    "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", 
    "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn10_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", 
    "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", 
    "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", 
    "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", 
    "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", 
    "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", 
    "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", "nZn100_", 
    "nZn100_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", 
    "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", 
    "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", 
    "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", 
    "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn1_", 
    "Zn1_", "Zn1_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", 
    "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", 
    "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", 
    "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", 
    "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", 
    "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", "Zn10_", 
    "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", 
    "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", 
    "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", 
    "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", 
    "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", 
    "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", 
    "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_", "Zn100_")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -280L))
```

Comment: Do you have a function `std.error()` in your environment? Currently code throws an error because it is missing.

Comment: `std.error <- function(x) sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))` # Create own function

Comment: yes, i just noticed it starting giving me an error too: this didn't happen before, I just updated my packages and it started giving me issues...

Comment: that solved it! the std.error issue, i mean

Comment: I'm not even sure anymore, since i tried updating my packlages and now i can't even get a graphic at all... all i get is this error: Error in aggregate.data.frame(lhs, mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A programmatic solution to your problem. Since your levels need to be ordered you can convert to a factor and order the data prior to adding the labels manually since they don't have the requisite grouping information.

```
std.error <- function(x) sd(x) / sqrt(length(x)) # Create own function

# A dplyr solution
library(tidyverse)
aa1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=mean)
bb1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=sd)
ee1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=std.error)
cc1 <- merge(aa1, ee1, by=c("day", "type")) %>% 
  mutate(sorter=factor(type)) %>% 
  arrange(sorter)
# In base R
aa1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=mean)
bb1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=sd)
ee1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=std.error)
cc1 <- merge(aa1, ee1, by=c("day", "type"))
  cc1$type=factor(cc1$type)
  cc1 <- cc1[order(cc1$type),]
colnames(cc1)[3:4] <- c("mean", "se")
cc1$number <- Number # change to lower case in the data frame to not confuse with original vectore

ggplot(data= cc1, 
       aes(x = type, y = mean, fill = day))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position= "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="", y="", title="") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se,
                    ymax = mean+se), 
                position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(aes(x=type, label=number, y = mean+se),
            # inherit.aes = F,
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-1.5, size = 4) +
  ylim(0, 60)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to re-install literally everything related to R as it seems part of the issue also stemmed with either the program or the packages updates, but this solved my initial issue: i just tested it and it looks perfect, thank you for your help and patience.

Comment: Sure, package updates can be tricky, sometimes functions you have used become deprecated and suddenly you are thrown errors after an update. Glad you got it straightened out!

Answer (score 3):

If you change the "Number" vector, to a vector of numbers, as characters, that will help you see whats going on.

```
Number <- as.character(1:35)
```

Yo will notice that the labels dont go from left to right, but they are first related to the days

[image: plot with numbers]

you could use this information to adjust your labels vector

UPDATE: based on that information, you could do this (it is not the most elegant solution, but it works)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

std.error <- function(x) sd(x) / sqrt(length(x))


Number <- c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
            "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
            "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
            "a", "b", "b", "c", "c",
            "a", "a", "a", "a", "a",
            "ab", "a", "ab", "ab", "b",
            "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")

# get the labels in the right order
order.in.plot=c(1,8,15,22,29,2,9,16,23,30,3,10,17,24,31,4,11,18,25,32,5,12,19,26,33,6,13,20,27,34,7,14,21,28,35)
position=data.frame(order.in.plot,Number, stringsAsFactors = F)
position=position %>% arrange(position)
Number=position %>% pull(Number)


aa1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=mean)
bb1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=sd)
ee1 <- aggregate(IBR ~ day + type, data=IBRindex, FUN=std.error)
cc1 <- merge(aa1, ee1, by=c("day", "type"))
colnames(cc1)[3:4] <- c("mean", "se")

ggplot(cc1, aes(x = type, y = mean, fill = day))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position= "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(x="", y="", title="") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        
  ) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se,
                    ymax = mean+se), 
                position = "dodge")+
  geom_text(aes(label=Number, y = mean+se),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-1.5, size = 4) +
  ylim(0, 60)
```

[image: plot with the right labels]

Comment: Jup, this is the answer you are looking for

Comment: that does seem to help!

Comment: @juan_bzt +1 for recognizing the issue! See my answer below this can be done without the need to "hard code" the positions

Comment: @juan_bzt thank you! I will go for the solution below as it easier for me to code for future similar graphs (i'm barely literate in code as is) but i appreciate all the same your work on finding the issue and providing a solution!